# mottie tablesorter, custom filter synched over multiple tables

Tags: tablesorter

I have multiple tables with exactly the same custom filters.  How do I sync the filters amongst all my tables so that if the user changes the filter on one of my table, it changes the same filters on all the other table as well?  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/897/) on the [home wiki page](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki) that demonstrates the method to use. I hope this is what you are requiring:

```
var ts = $.tablesorter,
    sorting = false,
    searching = false;

$('table')
    .on('sortBegin filterEnd', function (e, filters) {
        if (!(sorting || searching)) {
            var table = this,
                c = table.config,
                filters = ts.getFilters(table),
                $sibs = c.$table.siblings('.tablesorter');
            if (!sorting) {
                sorting = true;
                $sibs.trigger('sorton', [c.sortList, function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        sorting = false;
                    }, 500);
                }]);
            }
            if (!searching) {
                $sibs.each(function () {
                    ts.setFilters(this, filters, true);
                });
                setTimeout(function () {
                    searching = false;
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    })
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ['filter']
    });
```